# Image Loader Bitmap Cache

Tags: android, bitmap, universal-image-loader, memorycache, image-load

I show the image in android apps with image loader that image stores in local cache in bitmap. In certain device, the image has clipped and show only 30-50% but if apps uninstall and install again, the image show full and not clipped. In other device, the image show full and not clipped. The internet connection is good. How to solve this problem? Thank you.

Comment: Did you look at the cache to make sure that bitmaps aren't getting corrupted ?

Comment: Make sure you cleanup the necessary resources, before the app exits.

Answer (score 0):

You can dump app cache programmatically if you need to. 2nd make sure your setting up sufficent space for the image cache based on image size you save.